# hr should be longer (width) than div

Tags: html, css, width

i have a webpage and use the `<hr>` tag for separation of content when the page is displayed on tablets. it look like this:

[image: image of webpage.]

at the red rectangle the line should continue. however, it does not. what do i have to change in html/css in order to let the `<hr>` continue until the border of the page?

the page is here: http://crossroads-festival.org/test2015/en/film/almaen
please note to redue the browser width to at least 811px for the horizontal line to show up.

thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**
the css for `<hr>` is

```
hr {
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background: none;
}
```

the css for the `divider-mobile` class is:

```
.divider-mobile {
  margin-top: 3.125em;
  margin-bottom: 3.125em;
  overflow: visible;
  border: none;
  color: #888888;
  background-color: #888888;
  height: 1px;
  width: 150%;
  margin-left: -25%;
}
```

in the html i use it like this:

```
<hr class="divider-mobile">
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. Specifically, your HTML and CSS.

Comment: the code can be looked at: http://crossroads-festival.org/test2015/en/film/almaen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hky7zpfm - appears to stretch more than enough :)

Comment: Isn't that what bottom borders are for?

Comment: hm yes. but still on my webpage (http://crossroads-festival.org/test2015/en/film/almaen) it's not working... some other thing influences it, obviously. see screenshot. however, i cannot find what it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have:

```
#filmcontent {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

That is preventing the negative margin on your `<hr>` from going to the edge of the page.

You'll also want to remove the `width: 150%;` and `margin-left: 25%` on the `<hr>` and instead do...

```
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
```

(Where 20px is equal to the padding on `#content .entry-content`)

That will get you your desired effect!

Comment: hm almost there. i now set `margin-left` and `margin-right` as you said. i also removed `width` on `<hr>`. i also removed  `overflow-x: hidden`. however, then the `<hr>` does not get displayed at all. i have to again add `width: 100%` to get it to appear again. of course, then it's too short.. moreover it seems to ignore the margin (see orange area on top of `<hr>` here: http://i.imgur.com/1MRmeeM.png ) i appreciate one more try. thanks!

Comment: i played around a bit more and now it works. basically as you suggested. big thanks for your help (in contrast to annoying comments on my original question!)